# How to run external console app from python and communicate with it in the background

Tags: python, haskell, sublimetext3, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to develop simple SublimeText plugin for Haskell auto completion and type information.

The way I'd like to achieve that is by using haskells repl and communicating with it through stdin / out, but I'd like to keep repl running in the background (don't want console window visible during development).

So.. the question is essentially **how can I run repl as background process and pass some text to it and read its response?**

Comment: do you know of ghc-mod - it should already provide some form of autocompletion, also there is ndmitchell's ghcid project, which you should look up. for sublime i found https://github.com/SublimeHaskell/SublimeHaskell that already provides auto-completion

Comment: I plan to use intero for that, but this is just my little side project + SublimeHaskell is not very good in my opinion. @epsilonhalbe